# Not able to get the list of file in a .tar file in Java

Tags: java, tar

I'm trying to return a list of file names from inside of a tar file. I'm using the code below, but when it gets to the while loop, it immediately goes to the catch exception and says "java.io.IOException: Error detected parsing the header

Below is the code I'm using. Can you help me figure out why this doesn't work?

```
public List<String> getFilesInTar(String filename) {
  List<String> foundFiles = Lists.newArrayList();
  String filePath = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "Downloads" + File.separator + filename;
  try {
      TarArchiveInputStream tarInput = new TarArchiveInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath));
      TarArchiveEntry entry;
      while ((entry = tarInput.getNextTarEntry()) != null) {
          if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
              foundFiles.add(entry.getName());
          }
      }
      tarInput.close();
  } catch (IOException ex) {
      log.error(ex.getMessage());
  }
  return foundFiles;
}
```

Comment: What is the name of the file?  Is it a compressed tar?

Comment: File appears to be corrupt. Can you list it using `tar`?

Comment: @VGR the file name is downloaded_files.tar.gz ... I believe the .gz means it's compressed.

Comment: @user207421 Do you mean list it in a terminal window? With a command like, `tar -ztvf downloaded_files.tar.gz` ?

Comment: @rlw182 Yes, of course I do. I'm surprised you even asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is not a tar file.  It’s a compressed archive of a tar file.

You cannot open it as a tar file, as is, for the same reason you can’t read a text file while it’s in a zip archive:  the bytes representing compressed data are not themselves readable.

The `.gz` extension of your filename indicates that it was compressed using gzip, which is common when compressing tar files.  You can use the [GZIPInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html) class to uncompress it:

```
  TarArchiveInputStream tarInput = new TarArchiveInputStream(
        new GZIPInputStream(
            new BufferedInputStream(
                new FileInputStream(filePath))));
```